# jumping man -Small basics

Tags: smallbasic

```
Shapes_Init()
Shapes_Add()
While("True")
Shapes.Rotate(shp[3]["obj"],300) 
Shapes.Rotate(shp[4]["obj"],-300) 
Shapes.Rotate(shp[5]["obj"],90) 
Shapes.Rotate(shp[6]["obj"],90) 
Program.Delay(1000)
Shapes.Rotate(shp[3]["obj"],-300) 
Shapes.Rotate(shp[4]["obj"],300) 
Shapes.Rotate(shp[5]["obj"],180) 
Shapes.Rotate(shp[6]["obj"],180) 
Program.Delay(1000)
Shapes.Rotate(shp[3]["obj"],300) 
Shapes.Rotate(shp[4]["obj"],-300) 
Shapes.Rotate(shp[5]["obj"],90) 
Shapes.Rotate(shp[6]["obj"],90) 
endwhile

Sub Shapes_Init
  X0 = 10        ' x offset
  Y0 = 50       ' y offset

  shp[1] = "func=ell;x=60;y=-5;width=50;height=45;bc=#6A5ACD;" 
  shp[2] = "func=rect;x=40;y=42;width=100;height=150;bc=#6A5ACD;"      
  shp[3] = "func=rect;x=14;y=50;width=12;height=60;angle=35;bc=#6A5ACD;"  
  shp[4] = "func=rect;x=155;y=50;width=12;height=60;angle=-35;bc=#6A5ACD;"
  shp[5] = "func=rect;x=130;y=195;width=12;height=60;angle=180;bc=#6A5ACD;"
  shp[6] = "func=rect;x=40;y=195;width=12;height=60;angle=180;bc=#6A5ACD;"

EndSub

Sub Shapes_Add
  GraphicsWindow.Width=1200
  GraphicsWindow.Height=700
  For i = 1 To Array.GetItemCount(shp)
    GraphicsWindow.BrushColor = shp[i]["bc"]
    If shp[i]["func"] = "rect" Then
      shp[i]["obj"] = shapes.AddRectangle(shp[i]["width"], shp[i]["height"])
    ElseIf shp[i]["func"] = "ell" Then
      shp[i]["obj"] = shapes.AddEllipse(shp[i]["width"], shp[i]["height"])
    EndIf
    Shapes.Move(shp[i]["obj"], X0 + shp[i]["x"], Y0 + shp[i]["y"])
    If shp[i]["angle"] <> 0 Then
      Shapes.Rotate(shp[i]["obj"], shp[i]["angle"])
    EndIf
  EndFor
EndSub
```

Trying to come up with animation of jumping man in small basics.Just came up with work around which is working fine. Is there any other better way to achieve this. Also I need to change color when each time he jumps. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do is to use the Litdev extension, which can be found here: http://litdev.co.uk/

What you can do with this is LDShapes.AddAnimatedImage. This makes it so you can add a spritesheet like this: http://www.inkfood.com/wordprez/wp-content/uploads/SpriteSheet.png

Here is what it looks like: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cqOayLccGXo&feature=youtu.be

Here is the code that made that happen:

```
LDShapes.AddAnimatedImage("C:/SpriteSheet.png","True",12,3)
```